# Coinbase outgoing transaction never changed destination account balance?

Tags: coinbase.com

The transaction can be tracked at https://blockchain.info/tx/47068b561814a19a9613946185d527c7ba6eb3b6ed0cf17554fc80c27d7f0d4e?show_adv=false.

Although the transaction has been already been confirmed many times the balance of the destination account 1AQ27x3NQDpj5AGjGAKkvrcJW4RWvmhstX still shows 0.

The Coinbase source account https://blockchain.info/address/127SXekKqYsY6EbASqkvSZ4ZfF31qGKG93 shows "No transactions found for this address, it has probably not been used on the network yet."

Is that phantom transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain.info must have missed a block or had some other complication with their database.

http://blockr.io/address/info/127SXekKqYsY6EbASqkvSZ4ZfF31qGKG93